# Adding UIButton that covers couple of consecutive UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am stuck with adding a UIButton on top multiple uitableviewcells in a uitableview. When I try doing it basically I am trying to do achieve this user interface 
[image]
I have idea to add them as a UIView on top the uitableview cells but its getting complicated as when I change the mode of the iPhone they all stay and cannot be rotated along with the tableview.

If I am able to add them within the contentview of the cel then there willbe no overhead f rotation and scrolling but the problem is I cant overlap the button over 2 or 3 cells(each time row is a cell) , if anyone can give some idea that would be really appreciable.
Thanks in advance.
AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your right about that a view can't go past its content view so you can't have your button in a cell, but you could add the button as a subview to the tableView directly since UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. The following code assumes all cells have the same height.

```
    let cellHeight = tableView.heightForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(0, 0))// Take the height of the first cell for use in calculating button frame

 //I made variable names as descriptive as possible so you know what you would need to create for each button.
    let buttonFrame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, cellHeight * startRowOfButton, buttonWidth, cellHeight * numberOfRowsButtonCovers)

    button.frame = buttonFrame

    tableView.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: Just realized u tagged obj-c instead of swift let me know if you need me to convert the code I wrote into obj-c for you.